# Can't make my python code work with Django and Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

Guys i am new with Django and would highly appreciate your help.

The data is retried form DB. The idea is that a user enters product name in the search field and get its info and analysis:

```
views.py

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StockingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_f = form.save(commit=False)
            prinf = form_f.prinf

            prod=Product.objects.get(product=prinf)
            sales2019=Sales_2019.objects.get(product=prinf)
            sales2018=Sales_2018.objects.get(product=prinf)

            context={
            'product':prod , 'sales_2019':sales2019,'sales_2018':sales2018,}

            return render(request, 'staff/info.html', context)

    else:
        form =  StockingForm()
        return render(request, 'staff/all.html', {'form': form})
```

In `models.py`

```
class Sales_2019(models.Model):
    product=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gloves=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    bags=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
```

I have created seperate file `code.py`:

```
gloves=[sales2019.gloves,sales2018.gloves]
bags=[sales2019.bags,sales2018.bags]

analysis_1=[a/b for a,b in zip(gloves,bags)]

sales2019.gloves,sales20198.gloves, are values i do not know can i put in index them in `code.py` file?
```

My questions: how to make the code from code.py to work in view. py where it takes values from user input and sents back to code.py and make calculation and how to show result `analysis_1` ?

Would be helpful if you could share some example of code to better understand.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how models work and what they represent...

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand the problem, but i'm not so sure.

You have to import the code.py in your views, if they are in the same directory is like below, after that you need set the variable to take results of the function and pass parameters to it:

views.py:

```
from .code import name_function
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StockingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_f = form.save(commit=False)
            prinf = form_f.prinf
            prod=Product.objects.get(product=prinf)
            sales2019=Sales_2019.objects.get(product=prinf)
            sales2018=Sales_2018.objects.get(product=prinf)
            name_variable = name_function(sales2018, sales2019)
            context={
            'product':prod , 'sales_2019':sales2019,'sales_2018':sales2018,}
            return render(request, 'staff/info.html', context)

    else:
        form =  StockingForm()
        return render(request, 'staff/all.html', {'form': form})
```

In your code.py you need to create a function that takes the parameters and return the value

```
def name_function(sales2018, sales2019):
     gloves=[sales2019.gloves,sales2018.gloves]
     bags=[sales2019.bags,sales2018.bags]

     analysis_1=[a/b for a,b in zip(gloves,bags)]
     return analysis_1
```